# How can I disable square-bracket-prefixed mappings, so I can then remap a single-press square bracket without having to wait for the "timeoutlen"?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I was looking through the [default mappings for square brackets](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimindex.html#[), and I really don't need most of that functionality. I would like to disable these mappings, then use `nnoremap [ [[` and `nnoremap ] ]]` to be able to jump between functions/definitions with one keystroke. Is this possible?

Perhaps I can turn on `set timeout` and `set timeoutlen=0` for an individual remap...

Comment: You asked this one earlier, but the other one has an answer (which should work for both).

Comment: Actually, the solution in the other thread turned out not to work (try it for yourself) for brackets, although it did work for `<` and `>` perhaps because the latter waits for a **motion**, while the former is a **special command-prefix**. Can we re-open this? Not sure how.

Comment: No I'll take your word for it. Apologies! Nominated for reopening. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
nnoremap <nowait> ] ]]
nnoremap <nowait> [ [[
```

actually *does* work in plain text files, the problem is that many filetypes have custom `<buffer>` mappings for `[[`/`]]`.  In this case, a global `<nowait>` map fails because there are still `<buffer>` mappings with that prefix.  We need to make our mapping `<buffer>` as well.  However, there are problems

- We cannot use `nnoremap <nowait><buffer> [ [[` because this would use vim's default `[[` not the appropriate filetype's.
- We cannot use `nmap <nowait><buffer> [ [[` because this would create a recursive mapping with itself.

A solution is to use `<buffer>` maps with `:normal`:

```
nnoremap <silent><nowait> [ [[
nnoremap <silent><nowait> ] ]]

function! MakeBracketMaps()
    nnoremap <silent><nowait><buffer> [ :<c-u>exe 'normal '.v:count.'[['<cr>
    nnoremap <silent><nowait><buffer> ] :<c-u>exe 'normal '.v:count.']]'<cr>
endfunction

augroup bracketmaps
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType * call MakeBracketMaps()
augroup END
```

Note that many filetype's `[[`/`]]` implementations don't take a count.