# Can I disable the >> and >{motion} commands, then remap the single keystroke > to "indent this line"?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I never really use the other commands, and it would be nice to be able to indent/dedent lines this way. The solution for this may be similar to the solution for the [question I asked here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13273/how-can-i-disable-all-square-bracket-prefixed-mappings-so-as-to-remap-square-br); perhaps involving temporarily setting `timeoutlen=0`. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<nowait>` option to tell Vim not to wait for any more keys and stop looking for longer mappings.

```
nnoremap <nowait> > >>
nnoremap <nowait> <lt> <lt><lt>
```

Note: `<nowait>` requires Vim 7.4+

Personally, I would not recommend these mappings. You can use `>>` or `>{motion}` to do your initial indent/shift then use `.` to repeat the command.

For more help see:

```
:h :map-nowait
:h key-notation
:h .
```