# How to map shortcut to double square brackets using the leader key

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'd like to assign [[ to leader[ and ]] to leader].

I've tried the obvious:

```
let mapleader=" "
nnoremap <leader>[ [[
nnoremap <leader>] ]]
```

but the former mapping doesn't work.

I've tried with just those lines in _vimrc, and can reproduce this on both Vim8 on windows and Neovim (reasonably recent build from source) on RHEL.

Note: The obvious duplicate question doesn't apply to this one because I have no problem when not using the leader key.

Comment: Almost exactly duplicate in the sense that this answer should explain the behavior you are seeing and give you a possible solution https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13273/how-can-i-disable-square-bracket-prefixed-mappings-so-i-can-then-remap-a-single/13406#13406

Comment: That answer doesn't mention leader keys, and I have no problem performing a non-leader mapping, so I'm not sure it's relevant.

Comment: You need `nmap` not `nnoremap`.

Comment: The code given works for me. Try starting vim with `vim -u NONE` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Mass Why would he need to take out `nore`?

Comment: @tumbler41.  Because filetypes override `[[` and `]]` and `nnoremap` will use vim's built-in `[[` and `]]` instead.  The code works properly when editing plain-text.  (Not posting as an answer since I'm not 100% sure this solves the problem).

Comment: Using nmap moves the cursor down after half a second or so.  I thought I could reproduce the problem with -u NONE but currently I can't. Hmm.  I'm editing a c file.